# Too many async/awaits during one request causes hanging in ASP.NET Core 3.0 on Linux

Tags: c#, async-await, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-3.0

I can't provide specific details about our web application, but with posting this question I hope that someone can point me to the right direction.

We have a Web API that has one coarse-grained request, fetching lots of data from the DB and from Azure Table Storage. It was running on ASP.NET Core 2.2 on Windows in Azure AppService (Web App) and we haven't had any issue with it so far. Web client calls this request and users are expecting the request to last 10-20 seconds, as it loads bunch of data in one go. And they make this request 2-3 times per day. This is fine.

Last week we updated our code to run on ASP.NET Core 3.0 and we changed hosting to be on Linux under Azure AppService (Web App) P2V2 tier (7GB RAM and 2 cores).

The issues that we are experiencing is that sometimes this request will just never return a response. And it is quite random - sometimes it returns, but maybe 1 in 6 times it fails to return a response. No exception is being thrown, nothing in Application Insights. Nothing. Silence. The web client would timeout the request eventually after 4 minutes. And it doesn't happen under heavy load either. There could be no requests coming in to the server, just this one and it happens to hang.

With tracing messages, I found out that the hanging is always happening on the same 'await' query against the DB. I thought there was something wrong with EF Core (we use 3.0 now). I thought it was a problem because of AsNoTracking call, or ProjectTo (from AutoMapper). Tried multiple things - same issue. I remove the await call and changed from ToListAsync to just plain old ToList and suddenly the hanging started happening on the next 'await' query in line. With multiple tests, I confirmed once again that it always happens to that same 'async' query. When it hangs, it is always hanging on the 5th 'await' line. Now, I removed 'await' calls from all EF queries after the 4th and replaced ToListAsync with ToList. Now, the next 'await' in line is the call to Azure Table Storage and, as you might have guessed, **hangs again!**.

So, I decided to remove all 'async/await' from this API request and replace them with synchronous calls. And so far, there have been no issues reported.

I would appreciate if anyone can give me some pointers about what can be the cause of this behavior.

Comment: Just to be clear, I hope this is "async all the way" and you are never synchronously waiting for an async function?

Comment: Can you provide source code?

Comment: If you can create a repro you can open an issue on the appropriate repo (depending on whether it's in the runtime, the libraries or something else altogether). Without a repro, this is an interesting story, but not actionable for anyone else. The "right direction" may be a rewrite, or it may be a bug hunt, or maybe some physical host somewhere has a bad memory chip (unlikely, but stranger things have happened). Even an "I think I've seen something similar" story could be a complete red herring.

Comment: I'm with @HansKeﬆing. That is a classic symptom of synchronously waiting for an asynchronous method. But we need to see some code to be able to tell you anything for sure.

Comment: Once, I had a similar issue, some query just made everything stop and just hang for infinty. After lots of search, I was able to see that the table I was querying was locked by another service, so my application would wait for the table to be unlocked, which would never happen, so it just hanged for eternity. When it was hanging, I closed the service with the locked table and it returned the result. Not sure if this is your case, but please check if some table isn't locked. I'm not an expert in DB, and have now idea how to lock or unlock a table, but hope this helps.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing yes it was async all the way. Now I changed all calls to 'sync' and we are not experiencing any issues. 
Thanks everyone for commenting. I will try to reproduce this with a simple project and post the results.

Comment: I would appreciate if anyone can provide a way to debug async 'hanging'. Because, in our case there is no exception being thrown, so it is impossible to see what's causing the issue. This was a simple update from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.0, update to appropriate libraries (EF Core etc) and changed hosting to Linux. The code that has been working for almost 2 years on 2.x hasn't been touched at all.

Comment: It sounds like a deadlock, and in such a case, you won't get an exception, because nothing will ever happen; it's literally just stuck, doing nothing. The fact that switching to sync "fixes" the issue, seems to bear that out. Make sure you're async all the way down the call chain, and not blocking on anything with `Wait()`, `Result`, etc.

Comment: Analyzing wait chains is harder than crashes, but not impossible. In bad cases this may involve going down to the native debuggers and then tying that back to managed code, however. This can be tricky especially with Core on Linux, as the experience there is less comfortable than WinDbg + SOS. Which is why a repro is so useful, as it allows people who *are* comfortable with this to dig in with whatever advanced tooling they're comfortable with. As a first approach to zoom in, see if Windows vs. Linux makes a difference, and swapping out storage for something else (local files).

Comment: Thanks everyone for chipping in. We recently upgraded to .NET core 3.1 and upgraded all the libraries to latest version. Now, from time to time I see exceptions in our logs that says "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Unknown error 258". Outer exception is "Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.". It seems like this happens when there is no thread available to handle the response from the server. Any ideas now? Could be related to my original question.